# How to fix "Query returns and empty value" error in google spread sheet

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have the following code. I've read many threads on how to solve query returning empty value but none of them worked in my case.
I've also shared a workaround Google spreadsheet. 
What I'm going to do is that search first tab by query and if it matched, show a green tick, otherwise show a red cross.
The code below works for green tick but in case of red cross, it shows an error.

How the code below is expected to operate:
It makes a query on tab1 and if student number is in column C (with some defined conditions) OR is in column D (without any condition), it shows a green tick, otherwise, it must insert a red cross.

```
if(OR(QUERY(LiveAttendanceForm!$A:$C, 
"select C
where A >= timestamp '"&TEXT(D$1, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")&"' 
and A <= timestamp '"&TEXT(D$2, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")&"' 
and C = "&$C5, 0)=$C5,Query(LiveAttendanceForm!$A:$D,"select D where D = "&$C5,0)=$C5),"✅","❌")
```

I also tried using `iferror` function before the query, but it shows all fields as true and makes all cells green tick. I'll be very grateful if someone can help me fix this annoying issue! The share Google sheet's link is below:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KfkA48OyOnZAPQAbtdEIs9AYaAPRFRFOpvQRM5QyPss/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to wrap your queries into `IFERROR`:

```
=IF(OR(IFERROR(QUERY(LiveAttendanceForm!$A:$C, 
 "select C
  where A >= timestamp '"&TEXT(D$1, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")&"' 
    and A <= timestamp '"&TEXT(D$2, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")&"' 
    and C = "&$C4, 0))=$C4,
       IFERROR(QUERY(LiveAttendanceForm!$A:$D,
 "select D 
  where D = "&$C4, 0))=$C4), "✅", "❌")
```

[image]